# Docker compose not showing running logs for some containers

Tags: docker, logging, docker-compose

I believe this issue only started once I upgraded my Docker Desktop to 4.6.1 (76265). I have a docker compose script which initializes five separate containers. Two are pre-built (redis and postgres), and three are launched from the same container built locally, initialized with different commands.

This locally built container is running Ruby on Rails, and is built using the `ruby:3.1.1-slim` container image. The three containers are run using, respectively, `bundle exec rails s`, `bundle exec sidekiq` and `bin/webpack-dev-server`.

Before this upgrade, the running docker compose logs would include stdout logging for all five containers. However, ever since the upgrade, it only includes logging for postgres, redis and webpacker. Rails server and sidekiq are not shown, and I need to run `docker compose -f` in other terminal windows to monitor the other containers' logs.

I'm not sure why this upgrade triggered this behavior, and have been unable to find anything which seems relevant. There's at least [one other open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68247792/docker-compose-logs-not-showing) SO post which seems related, but without any useful answers.

All three custom-built container instances run on the same network, on different ports. Also, all three include the lines `stdin_open: true, tty: true` which helps me connect to debugging breakpoints which trigger by using `docker attach`.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: This appears to be related to stdin_open & tty parameters, when I add them they no longer output logs when running docker compose up. Don't have an answer though, was just looking into the same issue.

Comment: Yup, can confirm this gives me those container's logs back. However, with this I can no longer connect to the containers when a debugging breakpoint is hit, so it's not a fix unfortunately as that's necessary functionality.